# Bootstrap CDN + WP // How to edit '.css’

Tags: php, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I’m building my website on Wordpress + Bootstrap CDN.
I decided to make it on CDN to have no problem with updates in the future plus I read that this way it’s a bit faster.

So the thing is I have a problem with styles.
I imported my local ‘style.css’ to ‘header.php’, but since ‘bootstrap.min.css’ from CDN also has its own parameters I can’t apply some things.

How do I rewrite CDN’s parameters? Or is there a way to edit this exact  ‘bootstrap.min.css’ file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What sort of changes do you want to make to the bootstrap css file? Also, I'd recommend using `wp_enqueue_style` in your `functions.php` file rather than in `header.php` (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style)

Comment: To override a class or id from bootstrap, you can write the id or class css in your php file which will given higher priority by browser. Also you can use '!important' to make it important.

Comment: A better technique would be to include your own CSS file *after* you include the CDN file, and just write whichever styles you need to this CSS file of yours. That way they will override the problematic styles in your CDN file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply just use `wp_enqueue_style` to load those files. Here is an example you can get an idea from.

```
function enqueue_my_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.9.1', true); // we need the jquery library for bootsrap js to function
wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', '//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), true); // all the bootstrap javascript goodness
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_scripts');


function enqueue_my_styles() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', '//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_styles');
```

and to write the rules just use `!important` in your `style.css` file.

When you use `wp_enqueue_style`, you have the option to take control on where your styles and script be used for further references. Here is an example how to use it.

```
function my_enqueue_stuff() {
  if ( is_page( 'landing-page-template-one' ) ) {
    /** Call landing-page-template-one enqueue */
  } else {
    /** Call regular enqueue */
  }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_stuff' );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Brian! But I don’t really understand how is it better than just put my ‘.css’ file after CDN in 'header.php’?

Comment: Well, one reason I can call is that you might not want to use bootstrap on some other aspect of your site, this way you have control over All and specific pages. Code updated

Comment: @VassiliBagrov You mostly welcome. By the way, for other sites you want to develop, take a look into Foundation Framework is Awesome, Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

@TylerH answered my question and it solved my problem.

> A better technique would be to include your own CSS file after you include the CDN file, and just write whichever styles you need to this CSS file of yours. That way they will override the problematic styles in your CDN file.

Thank you very much!